# Why the Related Question queue have questions that are duplicates?

Tags: support, duplicates

[image: RELATED_BAR]

On the `Related` bar while I'm looking Questions or creating one, appear related questions that are duplicated.

**EXAMPLE:**
In [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/180754/62483) you will see at the end of the list a related question called [`nvidia GTK warning`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161480/nvidia-gtk-warning?rq=1). This last one is a **duplicated question** but even so it appears on the `Related` menu.

This can't fix displaying the *original* question or by removing the duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think the original question is a duplicate of one of the related question or if the related question is a duplicate of another related question, etc., flag them for closure.

What you are doing is for the greater good for the community and the site and I am sure the mods would really appreciate it if you do so too.

The functionality of the related question side bar is to help the questioner to quickly go through related question of the same topic. It is possible that the related question answers the original question, in which case the questioner wouldn't have to duplicate the question at all. But, on occasions, the questioner might not actively check the related questions sidebar and that's when the community steps in and helps close the question if it should be rightfully closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I'm not questioning the `Related` functionality. What I say is: `Related` menu have some **Duplicate Questions** and how to solve this issue.

Comment: I thought I did answer that part. *if the related question is a duplicate of another related question, etc., flag them for closure.* So, if there are duplicate questions that aren't closed, just flag them for closure.

Comment: Yes, you're right but this questions already are closed.

Comment: It is intended. As long as the related question is related to the original question and have any valid answer, they will show up.

Comment: Absolutely agree. But it cannot be improved? I don't think that  it is intentional, maybe I'm wrong. Or maybe is unnecessary an improvement, I don't know.

Comment: Improve? It's intended because the answers in the closed question might actually be good or better than on the master question. If you are going to remove them from the side bar, you are unnecessarily penalising those who mistakenly answered a duplicate question and they answered it really well too.

Comment: Oh, right. Yes, you're right. I forget about the answers that could have those duplicates.

Comment: After this, maybe my question is closed :-)

Comment: Haha, don't worry. Your question is valid.